# parameter communication by using launch file

Tags: ros, roslaunch, parameter

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd like to use parameter communication by using launch file.

First, I make the following node.

```
#include ＜ros/ros.h＞                       
int a=0;
int b;
int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "param_test");    
  ros::NodeHandle nh;                                             
  nh.setParam("param_str",a); 
  
ros::Rate r(10);
while(ros::ok())
{
  nh.getParam("param_str", b);       
  ROS_INFO_STREAM(b);        
  r.sleep();
}
}
```

This node is only showing the value of "b".

then,I make the following launch file.

```
＜launch＞
＜node pkg="ros_p" name="ros_p_node" type="ros_p_node" output="screen"/＞
＜param name="param_str" type="int" value="1" /＞
＜/launch＞
```

I want to change the value of "b" to 1,but it showed 0.

waht is it incorrect?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/242562/parameter-communication-by-using-launch-file/) by [sasadasd](https://answers.ros.org/users/27743/sasadasd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 104 on 2016-08-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sasadasd](https://answers.ros.org/users/27743/sasadasd/) on 2016-08-28**:
I want to set the value 'b' by using launch file even though the initial value(a=0) is allocated .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

roslaunch guarantees that all of the parameters set in the launch file will be set before your node starts.

So roslaunch sets the parameter to 1 before starting your node.

Once your node starts, it immediately sets the parameter to 0.

Then your node reads the parameter, and gets the value 0.

It sounds like you want your node to have a default value for the parameter, and you want to override that from the launch file. the common way to do this is by explicitly specifying a default value when you get parameter.

This is documented on the [roscpp parameters page](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Parameter%20Server), and the syntax for it looks like:

```
int b;
nh.param<int>("param_str", b, 0);
```

This will fetch the value of the `param_str` parameter into b, and use the value 0 if the parameter is not set.
You can then set `param_str` in your launch file (as you have already done) to override the default value of 0.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-08-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sasadasd](https://answers.ros.org/users/27743/sasadasd/) on 2016-08-28**:
I achieved my goal by eliminating "nh.setParam("param_str",a);" and  "nh.getParam("param_str", b)" and replacing nh.param("param_str", b, 0).

Thank you so much.